# Python comparing 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I have a doubt and i tried with this code.

Im addin a new column to compare two columns so if they are equal return True and if they arent retunr False.

i Upload a pic of the code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3efNC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the equal-to operator (==) instead. For example:

```
Evo_FlagF3['new_column'] = Evo_FlagF3['0.0'] == Evo_FlagF3['sum']
```